# CollectionViewSource Filter not working when SortDescriptions are introduced before

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionviewsource

I define a `CollectionViewSource` like this, but it seems the filter is not working.

```
CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();

//oc IS AN OBSERVABLE COLLECTION WITH SOME ITEMS OF TYPE MyClass
cvs.Source = oc;           

//IsSelected IS A bool? PROPERTY OF THE MyClass
cvs.View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(input=>(input as MyClass).IsSelected == true);

//Major IS AN string PROPERTY OF THE MyClass
cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(
                           "Major", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

However I changed the code this way and everything was solved!

```
CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs.Source = oc;           

cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(
                           "Major", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

cvs.View.Filter = new Predicate<object>(input=>(input as MyClass).IsSelected == true);
```

Anyone knows way?

Comment: i presume that maybe adding a sort description affects the View property (maybe it creates a new one?)  so in the first case, you're adding a filter to a view, then the sort descriptions change effectively makes a new view?  (also, you have `cvs` and `cvs2` in your examples, so it doesn't look like it should matter either way...

Comment: you could quickly check if cvs.View is the same object after the sort descriptions change.  otherwise, isn't there some call on CollectionViewSource to invalidate it and?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should be asking yourself is...

> Why am I adding the sorting description to the CollectionViewSource
>   and the filter to the View?  Shouldn't I be adding them both to the
>   same object?

**The answer is YES!**

To add filter logic to the `CollectionViewSource` directly, you add an event handler for the `Filter` event.

Straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx), here is an example

```
listingDataView.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(ShowOnlyBargainsFilter);
private void ShowOnlyBargainsFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    AuctionItem product = e.Item as AuctionItem;
    if (product != null)
    {
        // Filter out products with price 25 or above 
        if (product.CurrentPrice < 25)
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Accepted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, as for why the filter is getting removed when you add a sort description.

When you add a `SortDescription` to a `CollectionViewSource`, behind the scenes it eventually hits this block of code.

```
Predicate<object> filter;
if (FilterHandlersField.GetValue(this) != null)
{
    filter = FilterWrapper;
}
else
{
    filter = null;
}

if (view.CanFilter)
{
    view.Filter = filter;
}
```

Clearly, it is overwriting the Filter you set on the View.

In case you are still curious, here is the [source code for CollectionViewSource](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/CollectionViewSource@cs/1305600/CollectionViewSource@cs).